# Error: Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available - Error when sending Parameters to a smart contract using infura

Tags: node.js, ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I am getting this error when trying to send data to a smart contract using infura.

```
Error: Returned error: The method eth_sendTransaction does not exist/is not available
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/home/pi/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at /home/pi/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:300:36
    at /home/pi/node_modules/web3-providers-http/lib/index.js:124:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5) {
  data: null
}
```

Smart contract -

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: SEE LICENSE IN LICENSE
pragma solidity ^0.8.7;
 
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
 
// Represents any device connected to the Raspberry Pi that you want to control
struct Appliance {
    uint256 id;
    string name;
    bool status;
    bytes1 pin;
}
 
contract HomeAutomationDemo is Ownable {
    uint256 nextId = 1;
    uint256 count = 0;
    mapping(uint256 => Appliance) public appliances;
 
    // Add a new appliance to the list
    function addAppliance(string memory name, bytes1 pin) public onlyOwner {
        appliances[nextId] = Appliance(nextId, name, false, pin);
        nextId++;
        count++;
    }
 
    // Remove an appliance from the list
    function removeAppliance(uint256 id) public onlyOwner {
        delete appliances[id];
        count--;
    }
 
    // This is the function that will be called when the user 
    // toggles the status of the appliance on the mobile app
    function toggleAppliance(uint256 id, bool status) public onlyOwner {
        appliances[id].status = !appliances[id].status;
    }
 
    // Update the details of an appliance
    function updateAppliance(uint256 id, string memory name, bytes1 pin) public onlyOwner {
        appliances[id].name = name;
        appliances[id].pin = pin;
    }
 
    // Get the details of an appliance
    function getAppliance(uint256 id) public view returns (Appliance memory) {
        return appliances[id];
    }
 
    // Get the list of appliances
    function getAppliances() public view returns (Appliance[] memory)  {
        Appliance[] memory result = new Appliance[](count);
        for (uint256 i = 0; i < nextId; i++) {
            if (appliances[i].id != 0) {
                result[i] = appliances[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
 
    // Get the total number of appliances
    function getAppliancesCount() public view returns (uint256) {
        return count;
    }
 
}
```

Nodejs -

```
const web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require("fs");


const CONTRACT_ABI = `[
        {
                "anonymous": false,
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "indexed": true,
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "previousOwner",
                                "type": "address"
                        },
                        {
                                "indexed": true,
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "newOwner",
                                "type": "address"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
                "type": "event"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                "name": "pin",
                                "type": "bytes1"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "addAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "appliances",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bool",
                                "name": "status",
                                "type": "bool"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                "name": "pin",
                                "type": "bytes1"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "getAppliance",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "components": [
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                                "name": "id",
                                                "type": "uint256"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "string",
                                                "name": "name",
                                                "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bool",
                                                "name": "status",
                                                "type": "bool"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                                "name": "pin",
                                                "type": "bytes1"
                                        }
                                ],
                                "internalType": "struct Appliance",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "tuple"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "getAppliances",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "components": [
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                                "name": "id",
                                                "type": "uint256"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "string",
                                                "name": "name",
                                                "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bool",
                                                "name": "status",
                                                "type": "bool"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                                "name": "pin",
                                                "type": "bytes1"
                                        }
                                ],
                                "internalType": "struct Appliance[]",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "tuple[]"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "getAppliancesCount",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "owner",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "address"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "removeAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "renounceOwnership",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bool",
                                "name": "status",
                                "type": "bool"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "toggleAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "newOwner",
                                "type": "address"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "transferOwnership",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                "name": "pin",
                                "type": "bytes1"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "updateAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        }
]`;
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x13d9FA79D364070510B410c2FaC1976F21E3e218";

const web3js = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/9e644c118b7c44068674e2d12a776536"));


var myAddress = '0x46Be881Fa6935a8FC969A4ddDFC74d625c558996';
const privateKey = Buffer.from('82f98661ea7e05ac4bad0965da4b8a1fab93cf27e606d1185a275c91f96aac9b', 'hex')
var contractABI =JSON.parse(CONTRACT_ABI);
var contractAddress = CONTRACT_ADDRESS;

contract = new web3js.eth.Contract(contractABI,contractAddress);


// first populate an appliance

async function main () {



let setAppliance = await contract.methods.addAppliance("fan", web3.utils.numberToHex(1)).send({from: myAddress});
console.log(setAppliance);


let applianceOnOff = await contract.methods.getAppliances().call();
console.log(applianceOnOff);
}



main()
 .then(() => process.exit(0))
 .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
});
```

I searched online and it seems infura doesn't support signing transactions. I tried some other fixes but unfortunately it didn't work. But calling functions from the smart contract does work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems, first you need to add your private key to the wallet to create a send transaction:

```
const privateKey = "82f98661ea7e05ac4bad0965da4b8a1fab93cf27e606d1185a275c91f96aac9b";
const account = web3js.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x' + privateKey);
web3js.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account);
```

And you can't use `await` with `contractInstance.method.send` format.
So your final code should be:

```
const web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require("fs");


const CONTRACT_ABI = `[
        {
                "anonymous": false,
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "indexed": true,
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "previousOwner",
                                "type": "address"
                        },
                        {
                                "indexed": true,
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "newOwner",
                                "type": "address"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "OwnershipTransferred",
                "type": "event"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                "name": "pin",
                                "type": "bytes1"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "addAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "appliances",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bool",
                                "name": "status",
                                "type": "bool"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                "name": "pin",
                                "type": "bytes1"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "getAppliance",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "components": [
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                                "name": "id",
                                                "type": "uint256"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "string",
                                                "name": "name",
                                                "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bool",
                                                "name": "status",
                                                "type": "bool"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                                "name": "pin",
                                                "type": "bytes1"
                                        }
                                ],
                                "internalType": "struct Appliance",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "tuple"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "getAppliances",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "components": [
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                                "name": "id",
                                                "type": "uint256"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "string",
                                                "name": "name",
                                                "type": "string"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bool",
                                                "name": "status",
                                                "type": "bool"
                                        },
                                        {
                                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                                "name": "pin",
                                                "type": "bytes1"
                                        }
                                ],
                                "internalType": "struct Appliance[]",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "tuple[]"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "getAppliancesCount",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "owner",
                "outputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "",
                                "type": "address"
                        }
                ],
                "stateMutability": "view",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "removeAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "renounceOwnership",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bool",
                                "name": "status",
                                "type": "bool"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "toggleAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "address",
                                "name": "newOwner",
                                "type": "address"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "transferOwnership",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        },
        {
                "inputs": [
                        {
                                "internalType": "uint256",
                                "name": "id",
                                "type": "uint256"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "string",
                                "name": "name",
                                "type": "string"
                        },
                        {
                                "internalType": "bytes1",
                                "name": "pin",
                                "type": "bytes1"
                        }
                ],
                "name": "updateAppliance",
                "outputs": [],
                "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
                "type": "function"
        }
]`;
const CONTRACT_ADDRESS = "0x13d9FA79D364070510B410c2FaC1976F21E3e218";

const web3js = new web3(new web3.providers.HttpProvider("https://sepolia.infura.io/v3/9e644c118b7c44068674e2d12a776536"));


var myAddress = '0x46Be881Fa6935a8FC969A4ddDFC74d625c558996';
const privateKey = "82f98661ea7e05ac4bad0965da4b8a1fab93cf27e606d1185a275c91f96aac9b";
const account = web3js.eth.accounts.privateKeyToAccount('0x' + privateKey);
web3js.eth.accounts.wallet.add(account);

console.log(privateKey);
var contractABI = JSON.parse(CONTRACT_ABI);
var contractAddress = CONTRACT_ADDRESS;
contract = new web3js.eth.Contract(contractABI, contractAddress);

// first populate an appliance

function main() {

    contract.methods.addAppliance("fan", web3.utils.numberToHex(1)).send({ from: myAddress, gas: 230000 })
        .on("receipt", (receipt) => {
            console.log("receipt:");
            console.log(receipt);
            contract.methods.getAppliances().call({ from: myAddress }).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            });
        });
}

main()
```

P.S. there is a problem with the `getAppliances` method, you need to debug it and redeploy the contract, but `addAppliance` method would work.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! But, again I m a little confused on the get part. Let's say I am sending value to the toggleAppliance function, an int and a bool value. On the Rpi, I will be running a nodejs that gets the value from the smart contract and runs function on the RPi to turn on anf off the device based on if conditions, and I will use a setInterval to keep it running. Do you think its possible? Here's an example of what I am trying to do - [https://pastebin.com/MqjNMXki] - I send values to smart contract from mobile phone, and RPI gets the value and execute functions

Comment: The pastebin link isn't working... the toggleAppliance function implementation in the code you shared the bool value is actually not being used, I don't thing you need to pass any bool value either. And one question from me is what do you mean by "RPi"?

Comment: Please remove the last square bracket from the pastebin link. And I guess I need to update the toggleAppliance function on the smart contract. I will explain again-  I need to send 2 values from my nodejs program on my mobile to the smart contract that stores the values in a variable (id and status). And on another nodejs program that will be running on m Raspberry PI (RPi) will call the smart contract and takes the value from the toggleAppliance function, and then executes functions based on if-else conditions. (turn on/off led lights).  And i will use setInterval() to keep it running

Comment: If you want to toggle the status value I don't think you have to send the status variable as an argument...however, if you want to update the status from your mobile you can create a updateStatus function like this: https://pastebin.com/eVimqyXJ
Also, Seems to me you are interested in the status of the appliance so, maybe return the status instead of getting the whole appliance like this: https://pastebin.com/6W9eWaf8

Comment: I finally figured it out, just changed my smart contract completely, and wrote a simple program from scratch, and it worked. Thanks for helping out though. I really appreciate that.